# Is this a viable amplifier circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mains, current-transformer

I am looking to measure my mains voltage input for a power monitoring circuit.  This is the first time I have messed with an opamp to read out a transformer, as well as my first time simulating in KiCAD.

Am I missing anything before I build this?

[Transformer Datasheet](https://5nrorwxhmqqijik.leadongcdn.com/ZMPT101B+specification-aidijBqoKomRilSqqokpjkp.pdf)

[image: Circuit Schematic]
[image: Simulator]

Comment: Can't you use a a regular voltage-reducing transformer? Get a 240V to 3V transformer, rated at 1VA. They are PCB-mount. OP-07 is a legacy design targeted for DC accuracy and needs 6V or higher supply. It's not anything you'd want to use from 5V, and is pretty much unnecessary overkill for this application. Just about any half-decent CMOS rail-to-rail jellybean op-amp would do the job. Of course with a voltage transformer there's no need for op-amps either. The secondary can be scaled down with a voltage divider and fed directly into an ADC.

Comment: Please provide a **pdf** data sheet link to the transformer

Comment: A PDF has been added.  Also I did not realize that PCB reduction transformers like that existed, I started using the ZMPT101B as it seemed to be made for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to this part of your post:

> opamp to read out a current transformer,

To be a "current transformer", the primary winding should be connected in series with the load it is monitoring, and the secondary winding must be connected across a resistor (called a "burden resistor").

I suspect T1 is not intended to monitor current, because:
(a) The primary of the T1 is not connected in series with any load.
(b) No burden resistor is shown in the schematic, unless this is already included within the component marked as T1.

If T1 is intended to monitor voltage, then there is a problem: The series resistors will cause inaccuracies due to any current drawn by the primary winding (terminals 1 & 1 of T1).  This primary current will have two components:
a) magnetising current, and
b) reflected secondary current due to the loading of secondary winding by the opamp circuit.

I suspect the (a) will dominate, since (b) should be very low (opamp input current).

Do you intend to measure mains voltage, or the current into a load connected to the mains, or both?

I would suggest the following links as being useful:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu454a/tidu454a.pdf?ts=1693705530858&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

https://www.pcbway.com/blog/technology/High_Precision_Digital_AC_Energy_Meter_Circuit_Voltage_Current_Power_KWh_3a6bf090.html

https://www.digikey.com.au/reference-designs/en/power-management/energy-metering-for-ac/531

**UPDATE 2023-09-04**
The OP has now added the transformer datasheet, and it is now clear that the transformer is a CT intended for use with low voltages applied to the windings.  Voltage measurement is possible provided the measured voltage is much larger than the rated winding voltage, and the current sampled from the measured voltage is limited to 2mA.

To proceed: firstly convert the measured voltage to current suitable for the CT primary using a resistor.  120kOhms is required to convert 240VAC (rms) to 2mA (rms).  I would suggest allow a certain over-range capability, so I suggest about 150kohm to give 1.6mA at 240VAC. At 2mA this extends the input voltage measurement range to 300VAC.

Secondly, select a suitable resistor on the secondary side to convert the current to a voltage within the ratings of the transformer.  The datasheet recommends 100ohm at 2mA, which means secondary voltage is:
100ohm * 2mA = 0.2V.
**Do not exceed this voltage otherwise accuracy will deteriorate**.

This is quite a low-level voltage & may need to be amplified to match the input range of your ADC.  Assuming your ADC input is 3.3V for full-scale, and assuming 240V at the input gives 1.6mA * 100 ohm = 0.16V, then the amplifier needs to have a gain of: 3.3V / 0.16 = 20.6 ==> 20. To include 300VAC within the measurement range of your ADC then adjust (reduce) gain accordingly.

I would suggest an amplifier followed by a precision rectifier to smooth the AC output waveform to DC suitable for the ADC to handle without excessive sampling rate, followed by a simple RC filter sufficient to remove ripple but not excessive to affect step-response.  Be sure to put the precision rectifier **after** the amplifier, since the output voltage of the transformer (0.16V) is simply too low for accurate conversion to DC using simple rectifiers.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I misspoke on my original post.  I intend to read voltage out of this 1:1 transformer.

I have added the datasheet, but I thought the series resistors were necessary to limit input current to 2mA per the specification of the transformer.

Comment: Hmmm, I would advise against using a 1:1 transformer, since the output voltage will be the same amplitude as the input voltage - which is lethal 240VAC!  Suggest sourcing a transformer with a much lower & much safer output voltage.    If you insist on using a 1:1 transformer, then the out a voltage divider on the secondary side to reduce the voltage to a safe level, then make sure you insulate all the terminals of the transformer and the voltage divider so you don't make accidental contact with them and get electrocuted.  Good luck.

Comment: I understand the concern, but the current limiting resistors on the primary should limit the input to milllivolts as 2mA is all the transformer can handle.

Comment: OK, everything is now much clearer after you have posted the datasheet of the transformer.  I have updated my response accordingly.  Cheers.

Comment: Am I fine doing my current-limiting resistor calculations with RMS voltage, or should I be using the peak voltage of 353.5v for 240v AC?

Also I stumbled across this website: https://innovatorsguru.com/zmpt101b/ Using this, wouldn't 100ohms be too low?

Comment: @Jeff  Use RMS to calculate the power dissipated in the resistor, then select resistor based on this.  That link you provided gave some guidance on how to do that selection.

Comment: @Jeff In regard to your question re: "Using this, wouldn't 100ohms be too low? "  Which 100 ohms are you referring to, is it the 100ohm mentioned in my answer, or the 100ohm mentioned in the link?  Regardless, both refer to the resistor on the **secondary** side of the transformer, not the primary side.  Am running out of room in this comment, will post a key part of that link you provided in the next comment.

Comment: Test copied from your link:
"ZMPT101B is a high-precision voltage Transformer. This module makes it easy to monitor AC mains voltage up to 1000 volts. A tiny little thing the size of a bouillon cube. Holds up to 4kV per breakdown voltage, the ratio of turns is 1: 1, but this is a current transformer of 2mA: 2mA. We feed it a current and remove the current. The input current is simply set by the resistor in series R1, and we use a sampling resistor R2 in parallel to get the output voltage."

The schematic diagram explains this & refers to the two resistors as R1 (primary)& R2 (secondary).